# Passing array in JQuery Script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, post

Been working on this dumb problem for two days now. If you can help I would sure appreciate it!

So my html goes like this:

```
<a class='selected' option ='2' category='1' price='1750.00'>Round Corners</a>
<a class='selected' option ='3' category='1' price='2200.00'>Chamfer Corners</a>
```

And then my script is:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    var passOptions = new Array();
    var i=0;
    $('.selected').each(function(){
        passOptions[i] = $(this).attr('option');
        i++;
    });
console.log(passOptions);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processsaveconfig.php?configid=<? echo $configid; ?>",
    data: { passOptionsArray : passOptions },
    success: function() {
        $('#pricediv').html(data);
    }
    });

});
```

My php page goes:

```
    $passopts = $_REQUEST['passOptionsArray'];

mysql_connect($serverpath, $dbusr, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("DELETE FROM se_config_opt_link
        WHERE se_config_opt_link.f_config_id = '$configid'");

foreach ($_POST['passOptions'] as $opts){

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO se_config_opt_link (f_config_id, f_opt_id)
        VALUES ('$configid', '$opts')");
};
```

In Firebug in the Console tab I get: ["1", "4", "7"]
But in the Response tab it reads:

**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **/home/users/c/companion/public_html/dynamic/builder_app/processsaveconfig.php** on line **17**

I'm stuck. If you can help I would really be grateful.

Comment: First things first, var_dump() it to see actually what kind of data you have

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert but shouldn't it be `$passopts['passOptions']` instead of `$_POST['passOptions']` in your `foreach`.

Comment: I'm using Jeremy's code but var_dump still outputs "NULL"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you're looking for this:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    var passOptions = [];
    $('.selected').each(function(){
        passOptions.push($(this).attr('option'));
     });
console.log(passOptions);
```

in your PHP, use something like this:

```
$myArray = $_POST['passOptionsArray'];
if (is_array($myArray)({

    ...

}
```

I expect that will make the difference.

Comment: OK, using this code, here is the Firebug "Response" now:
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt the `foreach ($_POST['passOptions'] as $opts){...` be more like `foreach ($_POST['passOptionsArray'] as $opts){...`